# Unable to get escape syntax to work in github actions on powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell, syntax-error, github-actions, escaping

```
PS C:\Users\sshuser_App\Downloads> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -q -t -i C:\Users\sshuser\.ssh\id_rsa_tmp sshuser@dbhost
```

First, The above ssh command works fine on Windows Powershell shell and help jump to Linux host `dbhost` ksh shell.

```
sudo docker exec -ti mongodockerimage mongo --port 27062  --authenticationDatabase '$external'  --authenticationMechanism PLAIN -u 'mydbuser' -p 'mydbpass'  --eval "db = db.getSiblingDB('testdb'); print(db.getName()); load('audit/masking_scripts/1mask.txt')"
```

Next, The above docker command works fine on a Linux host `dbhost` having `ksh` shell.

If I combine and run both the above commands from Linux runner bash shell it runs fine as below:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -q -t -i C:\Users\sshuser\.ssh\id_rsa_tmp sshuser@dbhost "sudo docker exec -ti mongodockerimage mongo --port 27062  --authenticationDatabase '\$external'  --authenticationMechanism PLAIN -u 'mydbuser' -p 'mydbpass'  --eval \"db = db.getSiblingDB('testdb'); print(db.getName()); load('audit/masking_scripts/1mask.txt')\""
```

The problem is when I combine both the commands and run it from github actions runner having PowerShell.

I tried escaping with `backtick` for `$` and for `double-quotes`

However, I get the below error:

```
PS C:\Users\sshuser_App\Downloads> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -q -t -i C:\Users\sshuser\.ssh\id_rsa_tmp sshuser@dbhost "sudo docker exec -ti mongodockerimage mongo --port 27062  --authenticationDatabase '$external'  --authenticationMechanism PLAIN -u 'mydbuser' -p 'mydbpass'  --eval `"db = db.getSiblingDB('testdb'); print(db.getName()); load('audit/masking_scripts/1mask.txt')`""
ksh: syntax error at line 1: `(' unexpected
PS C:\Users\sshuser_App\Downloads>
```

I would eventually want to variabilize the command like below:

```
run: |
  ${{ inputs.executesshstring }}@${{ inputs.targethost }} "sudo docker exec ${{ inputs.dockerImage }} mongo --port ${{ inputs.DBport }} --authenticationDatabase '`$external' --authenticationMechanism PLAIN -u ${{ inputs.DBuser }} -p ${{ inputs.DBpass }} --eval `"db = db.getSiblingDB('${{ inputs.DBname }}'); print(db.getName()); load('audit/masking_scripts/${{ inputs.executefilename }}')`""
```

The same error test case where linux works while windows fails here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/mongomaskwinvslinux/actions/runs/5931171744/job/16082465493

Can you please suggest what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Looks like you've changes 2 things at once - in your first command you're calling ```sudo docker ...``` from ```ksh``` but in the second you're calling it with an ```ssh ...``` wrapper from powershell. Could you try the middle step of running the ```ssh``` command on ```ksh``` to make sure *that*'s escaped properly and is valid syntax? Once you know that's valid you can try to escape it for PowerShell...

Comment: ssh in the original post always runs on powershell and never elsewhere. sudo docker always runs on ksh. if i fire only the ssh part from powershell I m able to login to linux host i.e `dbhost` successfully. Once there the `sudo docker` also runs fine. So in summary breaking the `ssh` and `sudo docker` is successful but combining them as one is when the syntax fals

Comment: if i combine them and run both on bash / ksh with using escape character as "\" instead of `backtick` then the combined command also works fine. @mclayton

Comment: Could you add the exact command to your question for reference?

Comment: @mclayton i updated the original post providing extra information for success and failure.

Comment: @mclayton I put the exact command and error in a running testcase link in the original post. Please check